# Should I actively try to tell If I am being ticketed?

Tags: european-union, traffic

I lived in Finland for two months. During these two months, I have submitted a form, where I told finnish postal service that my Finnish address is the one where they should deliver my mail.

A week ago I was photographed by an automated speed radar going 80 km/h in a 60 in a rental car. Immediately after that I had to unexpectedly leave Finland without cancelling the address with Finnish postal service.

Should I actively try to learn if I am in fact being ticketed, before any potential fine increases? If yes, how do I do that?

If it matters, I am a resident of another EU country, the address on my contract with the car rental company is my Finnish address, the rental company is a big multinational one (and also operates in my home country) and neither I nor anyone I know can check the mailbox at my Finnish address anymore.

Comment: It's possible that the ticket will be given to the rental car company who will then put this on your credit card automatically without sending you a bill/ticket. Usually the ticket goes to the registered owner referenced to the plate number, they probably can't tell who was physically at the wheel.

Comment: I would have expected the rental company to have the tickets and tolls at hand when you returned the car.

Comment: @user6726 I returned the car via parking it in a preapproved space and throwing keys in a glorified mailbox, an also the fine was likely not processed by then by authorities. The point is, should I expect them to send me an email, or just a letter to the address where I no longer reside?